# How to auto-initiate ESLint in Atom using modified rules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, eslint

I'm just getting into Atom and ESLint - heck still a noob using Node and npm.

I've got a project working fine with Atom, Linter and ESLint, and I customized the rules of the "standard" config (as opposed to Google or AirBnB).

When I start a new project, however, nothing is carried over.  It looks like I have to re-init ESLint, and then it asks for the config file again, which is obviously not my customized version.

How can I get ESLint to run automatically whenever Atom opens a JS file, using my custom rules?

Thanks in advance and let me know if my terminology is off...

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, we recommend checking `.eslintrc` files into source control. This makes sure that every developer working on a project is using the same ESLint config. However, if you want to have a shared config for all of your personal projects, you can put a `.eslintrc` file in your home directory. If a project doesn't specify its own `.eslintrc`, ESLint will look in your home directory and use that config instead. You can read more about that in our [configuring docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.